# zsh compinit: insecure directories

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

```
zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?
```

Running the `compaudit` returns the follows:

```
There are insecure directories:
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

Comment: If you don't have permission to change the ownership of the required folders as given in the answers, then open the `.zshrc`
file and put this line at the beginning of the file `ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX=true`.

Comment: How is this question possibly not considered to be about "software tools primarily used by programmers"? What profession is the primary user of zsh if not programmers?

Comment: Tried all comments. Only this command fixed it:
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/*

Answer (score 987, accepted):

**Note:** This answer is from 2012.

---

This fixed it for me:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

Credit: [a post on zsh mailing list](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2008/msg00566.html)

---

**EDIT:** As pointed out by @biocyberman in the comments. You may need to update the owner of `site-functions` as well:

```
$ sudo chown -R root:root /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

On my machine (OSX 10.9), I do not need to do this but YMMV.

**EDIT2:** On OSX 10.11, only this worked:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/zsh
$ sudo chown -R root:staff /usr/local/share/zsh
```

Also `user:staff` is the correct default permission on OSX, where `user` is actually your username (i.e. `whoami`, or `$USER`).  In other words:

```
$ sudo chown -R ${USER}:staff /usr/local/share/zsh
```

Comment: @kirill_igum by "no root" did you mean "no root _access_"? If so, then you should copy the files to a folder you have access to, fix your `.zshenv` and `.zshrc` to use the new folder and do the same `chmod` on the new folder as I've posted with the folder.

Comment: @kirill_igum see the mailing list message I've linked to.

Comment: To eliminate the warning, one must make sure both permission and ownership are correct. So in addition to the chmod command here, also do: `sudo chown -R root:root ./site-functions`

Comment: @biocyberman are you on linux? I am on OSX and `ls -l ./site-functions` shows me as the owner, not root and everything seems to be ok.

Comment: um ... please feel free to use the whole path instead of cd :)

Comment: I noticed that after setting the owner to root, write access needed to be revoked for both group and other. I modified the `chmod` command to `sudo chmod -R go-w zsh`.

Comment: what if you are not on the sudoers file but have an account that is in the sudoers file

Comment: Note: I had symlinks in `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions` to `/usr/local/Cellar` and had to `chown -R root:staff /usr/local/Cellar` also before this worked.

Comment: First proposal worked for me on my Ubuntu 17 distro.

Comment: Didn’t clarify whether it should be `root:staff` or `user:staff` for macOS. Confusing.

Comment: At least on 10.15 this will break homebrew.

Comment: had to use `-RL` instead of just `-R` to follow symlinks in `site-functions`

Comment: second instruction in the answer helped me to fix this issue
```sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/zsh/```

Comment: This answer did not work for me. The below answer with `compaudit` worked for me.

Comment: The last two lines did it for me on version 11.4
```$ sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/zsh $ sudo chown -R root:staff /usr/local/share/zsh
```

Comment: EDIT2 worked for me on macOS big Sur 11.4, thanks!

Comment: For me I had to change the zsh permission ownership to `root:admin` because I created a second Mac login user and these were set to my first login only. It also involved navigating to the symlinks and changing the permissions in the original files.

Comment: These aren't even existing directories.

Comment: Guys, this post was made in **2012**. Of course it's outdated and all.

I've made this post a community wiki so everyone can edit with whatever solution they find.

Ultimately tho, someone from zsh or homebrew should fix this for good.

Answer (score 849):

Removing group-write permissions with

```
compaudit | xargs chmod g-w
```

will do the trick.

See http://www.wezm.net/technical/2008/09/zsh-cygwin-and-insecure-directories/

Comment: Far better answer, it should be noted that `compaudit` can be used to diagnose problems like these as well as fix them.

Comment: Note that you may also have to change the owner of the files to root as well - I had to: `compaudit | xargs chown root`

Comment: This is definitely the best solution for me. I installed zsh and zsh-completions with Homebrew, so obviously did not want to change it to be owned by root.

Comment: `compaudit | xargs chmod g-w` together with `ompaudit | xargs chown root` worked for me too and appeared to keep HomeBrew happy. can someone explain whats going on a bit more.

Comment: This is very similar to the solution recommended by Homebrew: https://docs.brew.sh/Shell-Completion.

Comment: I just did what oh-my-zsh suggested: ```compaudit | xargs chmod g-w,o-w```
Which basically sets the permissions for whatever compaudit is complaining about by removing the write permissions for group and others.

Comment: I have `drwxr-xr-x 6 git root 4096 Aug 13 19:53 /path/to/insecure/`. `compaudit | xargs chmod g-w` will not help as `g` does not have `w` rights. What will help is `compaudit | xargs chown root` which will lead to `drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Aug 13 19:53 /path/to/insecure/`.

Comment: This would be a better answer if the 'why' explanation was included in the answer rather than simply linked.

Answer (score 278):

Most answers come with a solution, but do not mention why this warning occurs. Here's an excerpt from ZSH's [compinit](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html##Use-of-compinit):

> For security reasons compinit also checks if the completion system would use **files not owned by root or by the current user**, or **files in directories that are world- or group-writable or that are not owned by root or by the current user**. If such files or directories are found, compinit will ask if the completion system should really be used. To avoid these tests and make all files found be used without asking, use the option -u, and to make compinit silently ignore all insecure files and directories use the option -i. This security check is skipped entirely when the -C option is given.

Hence, the solution implies fixing one (or all) of the following:

- setting the current user as the owner of all the directories/subdirectories/files in cause:

  ```
  compaudit | xargs chown -R "$(whoami)"
  ```
- removing write permissions for group/others for the files in cause:

  ```
  compaudit | xargs chmod go-w
  ```

Another approach would be to skip these checks by using

```
compinit -u
```

but I don't really suggest this, as hiding problems under a rug only solves problems in the short run.

Comment: Thanks. I'm amazed that people would randomly type commands w/o actually understanding the problem.

Comment: What about a multi-user system? In such scenario, `chown -R "$(whoami)"` for files outside the home directory such as `/usr/local/` would not work. According to the docs, wouldn't it make more sense to make the files be root-owned?

Comment: I like this answer the best. Made me think about why this happened to me. Turns out it happened after adding another user to my user's main group. The directories under $HOME/.antigen/bundles were owned by my user and my group. So in my case removing that user from the group solved the issue.

Comment: This is one of the top three or so answers out of dozens. Like the other few great answers, it explains what it happening and offers solutions.

Comment: Changing file owner and changing file privilege fails, but `compinit -u` cure all!

Comment: This is an Excellent Answer!!! Well done thank you. This should be the best answer hands down.

Comment: I don't get the difference between `-u` and `-C`. Seems like they all do the same thing!

Answer (score 217):

Once you *understand* the cause, solution is *trivial* and *unequivocal*.

- **Cause**: the directories output by `compaudit` have *write* permission by either *group* or *others* (world-writable); or those files are owned by somebody else other than *root* or yourself.
- **Example**: In my case, `compaudit` gave me that:

```
% compaudit 
There are insecure directories:
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/share/zsh
```

And if we list the permission of those files/directories we have (in this case)

```
% ls -lh /usr/local/share 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  12 chbrandt  admin   384B Aug 14 10:45 aclocal
drwxr-xr-x   8 chbrandt  admin   256B Aug 14 10:45 doc
drwxr-xr-x   3 chbrandt  admin    96B Jul 24 21:00 fish
lrwxr-xr-x   1 chbrandt  admin    36B Aug 14 10:45 gettext -> ../Cellar/gettext/0.21/share/gettext
lrwxr-xr-x   1 chbrandt  admin    41B Aug 14 10:45 gettext-0.21 -> ../Cellar/gettext/0.21/share/gettext-0.21
lrwxr-xr-x   1 chbrandt  admin    37B Aug 14 10:45 gtk-doc -> ../Cellar/libidn2/2.3.0/share/gtk-doc
drwxr-xr-x   9 chbrandt  admin   288B Aug 14 10:45 info
drwxr-xr-x  58 chbrandt  admin   1.8K Aug 14 10:45 locale
lrwxr-xr-x   1 chbrandt  admin    41B Jul 27 17:12 luajit-2.0.5 -> ../Cellar/luajit/2.0.5/share/luajit-2.0.5
drwxr-xr-x   5 chbrandt  admin   160B Jul 27 17:12 man
lrwxr-xr-x   1 chbrandt  admin    33B Aug 14 10:45 nvim -> ../Cellar/neovim/0.4.4/share/nvim
drwxrwxr-x   3 chbrandt  admin    96B Jul 24 20:57 zsh
%
% ls -lh /usr/local/share/zsh 
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  4 chbrandt  admin   128B Jul 24 21:00 site-functions
%
% ls -lh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions 
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 chbrandt  admin    39B Jul 24 21:00 _brew -> ../../../Homebrew/completions/zsh/_brew
lrwxr-xr-x  1 chbrandt  admin    44B Jul 24 21:00 _brew_cask -> ../../../Homebrew/completions/zsh/_brew_cask
```

Now we easily spot the issue, don't we? Notice how `zsh/` and `zsh/site-functions` directories differ from the others...
That '`w`' allowing the `admin` group to modify them is not appreciated by zsh.

- **Solution**: Turn off that *group-writable* permission!

```
% chmod g-w /usr/local/share/zsh 
% chmod g-w /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

**That's it!** You're good to go. Open a new terminal and you should *not* see the "`zsh compinit: insecure directories`" message anymore ;)

Comment: What would generally cause these permissions to change for these directories?

Comment: @JaapWijnen I don't think they were _changed_, those directories were probably _created_ like that. I don't even consider that an error (if you think through the whole environment and `chbrandt` being a "su" and `admin` being a previledged group so on and so forth...). In this case in particular -- now answering your question -- those "wrong" permissions are/were probably the result of a tiny bug in the realm of zsh/homebrew...or a misunderstood feature ;)

Comment: @Brandt I think so too. My conclusion is to disable the compinit security check as changing ownership/permissions currently breaks homebrew.

Comment: This is the best answer, because it explains the problem, and shows a real concrete example while applying the solution

Comment: @Brandt I tried to apply your suggested changes but the error remains, I posted a separte question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431861/zsh-compinit-errors?noredirect=1#comment618960_431861

Comment: Excellent. This resolved my issue I was having when trying to enable aws cli command completion in zsh. If you want a one liner, here it is `compaudit | sed -n '2,$ p' | xargs -I{} chmod g-w {}`

Comment: Applied solution then ran `compaudit`, same directories still show as insecure

Comment: @Farid Interesting. Can you confirm those files/directories' permissions, please? They should be read-only (`chmod go-w`) to everybody but _you_ and `root` (according to the docs).

Comment: @Brandt I used this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63172694/5636313) and it worked

Comment: @Farid It means that the file(s) was/were being owned by somebody else other than you or root. Apparently you didn't pay attention to that, which is what my answer hopes to share.

Answer (score 58):

This works for my Mac since High Sierra update.

Remove the group write access:

```
sudo chmod g-w /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
sudo chmod g-w /usr/local/share/zsh
```

It’s best to keep the change limited to zsh directories.

Comment: This was the only fix that worked for me on Mac Catalina

Comment: Directories are still listed as insecure

Answer (score 49):

This answer is mostly a reference for myself to use in the future, as most answers do not provide a full-fledged solution. Here it is:

First run:

```
compinit
```

use `compaudit` if above does not work

For every single path that is printed run the following the commands:

```
sudo chown $(whoami) PATH_HERE

sudo chmod -R 755 PATH_HERE
```

Simple example, let's say one of the paths that gets printed after running compinit is "/usr/local/share/zsh". Then:

```
sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/share/zsh

sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/zsh
```

Comment: Just running `sudo chown $(whoami) PATH_HERE` worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This answer was the good one in my case.

Comment: This was the only one that actually worked for me. Thank you

Comment: Weird, that is only solution that worked for me

Comment: Only one that worked for me -- OSX Monterey 12.5.1

Answer (score 42):

This command updates all files/folders with correct permissions:

`compaudit | xargs chmod g-w`

You don't need to use `sudo` to change the owner - *unless the file belongs to root*

(Tested on macOS BigSur)

Comment: This should be the correct answer. While using "sudo" you must be cautious.

Comment: Nothing changed, `compaudit` still lists insecure directories

Answer (score 31):

I got the same warnings when I `sudo -i` starting a root shell, @chakrit's solution didn't work for me.

But I found `-u` switch of `compinit` works, e.g. in your .zshrc/zshenv or where you called `compinit`

```
compinit -u
```

NB: Not recommended for production system

See also http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Initialization

Comment: that was the only soution that worked for me. i was trying to use zsh with compinit on linux subsystem on windows 10

Comment: i tried all the other solutions and then this and its the only thing that worked for me. thank you,

Answer (score 27):

on Mojave, this did the trick :
`sudo chmod go-w /usr/local/share`

**[Update 2022]**

If using ZSH Completions installed through Homebrew, you should use:

`chmod -R go-w "$(brew --prefix)/share"`

As noted in the documentation: https://docs.brew.sh/Shell-Completion#configuring-completions-in-zsh

Comment: Better still: `sudo chmod -R go-w /usr/local/share`

Comment: `/usr/local/share/zsh` is enough.

Comment: If using zsh completions: https://docs.brew.sh/Shell-Completion#configuring-completions-in-zsh says to `chmod -R go-w "$(brew --prefix)/share"`

Answer (score 25):

I had the same warning lately on Catalina.
An easy workaround is to put this to the top of your .zshrc

```
ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX=true
```

Comment: This is the only solution that helped me on macOS Catalina 10.15.5! All the other things like `compaudit | xargs chmod go-w` or `compinit -u` doesn't seem to be work on this version of macOS

Comment: Only solution that worked on macOS BigSur 11.2.1 (20D74). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Best solution so far. Since I use separate account on my MacBook for multiple clients and personal use, I have multiple users using the zsh folders and I don't want to switch ownership all the time.
Adding this environment variable got rid of the annoying message at least.

Comment: Yup this is all that worked for me on Catalina too. Typical example of Apple's recent updates to their OS over the years just breaking more and more things and adding so many privacy and security checks that it's made OS X a totally unwelcome OS for any kind of development.

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer did not work for me on macOs Sierra (10.12.1). Had to do it recursive from /usr/local

```
cd /usr/local
sudo chown -R <your-username>:<your-group-name> *
```

**Note:** You can get your username with `whoami` and your group with `id -g`

Comment: I had t do it this way as well on Sierra, though on a multiuser system the correct user/group should be root:staff

Answer (score 15):

running this command worked for me on my `mac OS Catalina`:

`compaudit | xargs chmod g-w,o-w`

Comment: having only  this compaudit | xargs chmod g-w worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

**My machine:**

```
System Version: macOS 10.15.4 (19E287)
Kernel Version: Darwin 19.4.0
```

So here is what I did,

1. run `compaudit` and it will give you a list of directories it thinks are unsecure.
2. run `sudo chmod -R 755 target_directory`
   (example: `sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/zsh`)

**Exmaple:**

```
compaudit
```

returns:

> /usr/local/share/zsh

so I run

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/zsh
```

### read more here [link](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/issues/433#issuecomment-390600994)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on Big Sur

Answer (score 13):

**MAC OS X solution :**

```
$ sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/zsh
$ sudo chown -R root:staff /usr/local/share/zsh
```

Also "user:staff = default root user on OSX.

Answer (score 13):

I was getting this issue for the past may months tried few things but didn't worked. Finally what helped me was this. Get the list of insecure directories and then set the chmod of all of them as described below.

```
CLI# compaudit
There are insecure directories:
/usr/local/share/zsh
CLI# sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/zsh
Password:
```

Answer (score 12):

I fixed it by doing

```
sudo chown -R root:staff /usr/local/share/zsh
```

in my case other directories inside share/ also have "staff" group assigned

Answer (score 11):

I tried every solution posted, in the end none of them worked for my particular case. However, I want to extend my gratitude to the users who pointed me in the direction of the *ownership* being the real issue regarding multiple accounts, not the mode.
I'm posting this answer for anyone else with a similar setup (M1 + two accounts + /opt/homebrew/share).

Here is my setup:

I have an M1, running macOS Monterey 12.0.1, using Homebrew.

I have two accounts, one admin and one regular user (required split for work).
I only had the insecure directories issue on the regular user, both users use the same homebrew setup, with the following directories and files being affected by the issue:

```
/opt/homebrew/completions/zsh/_brew
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew_services
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_cargo
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_gh
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_j
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_lf
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_task
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_tldr
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_vifm
```

Changing the mode did nothing, in the end what fixed the issues was changing the ownership of every problem file and dir to root:admin, like so:

```
sudo chown root:admin /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/*
```

Originally, before the issue presented itself, my admin user owned everything, ownership therefore looked like this: *usr*:admin

This is what the site-functions dir looks like now, no issues:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root admin  30 Jul 19 19:41 _brew ->../../../completions/zsh/_brew
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root admin  79 Aug 10 20:26 _brew_services -> ../../../Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/completions/zsh/_brew_services
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root admin  59 Nov  6 16:28 _cargo -> ../../../Cellar/rust/1.56.1/share/zsh/site-functions/_cargo
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root admin  53 Dec  2 23:37 _gh -> ../../../Cellar/gh/2.3.0/share/zsh/site-functions/_gh
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root admin  56 Nov 30 15:21 _git -> ../../../Cellar/git/2.34.1/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root admin  61 Oct 13 11:12 _j -> ../../../Cellar/autojump/22.5.3_3/share/zsh/site-functions/_j
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root admin  50 Oct 23 18:52 _lf -> ../../../Cellar/lf/26/share/zsh/site-functions/_lf
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root admin  57 Nov  6 16:28 _task -> ../../../Cellar/task/2.6.1/share/zsh/site-functions/_task
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root admin  57 Nov 18 01:45 _tldr -> ../../../Cellar/tldr/1.4.2/share/zsh/site-functions/_tldr
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root admin  56 Oct 13 11:11 _vifm -> ../../../Cellar/vifm/0.12/share/zsh/site-functions/_vifm
```

Comment: This was my issue as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Following worked on M1

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.1
BuildVersion:   20C69

% compaudit
/opt/homebrew/share
```

Changed group permission from 775 to 755

```
% sudo chmod 755 /opt/homebrew/share

drwxr-xr-x   33 xenea  admin   1056 Feb  2 01:28 share
```

Comment: also worked on non-M1 MBP 2019 running OS 11.2

Answer (score 9):

These two lines have fixed for me.

```
sudo chown -R _user_:root /usr/local/share/zsh

sudo chown -R _user_:root /usr/local/share/zsh/*
```

Comment: Work for me! I use a network account on my PC - Ubutun 16.04

`sudo chown -R $(whoami):root /usr/local/share/zsh`
`sudo chown -R $(whoami):root /usr/local/share/zsh/*`

Comment: ...and if you have symlinks that point to somewhere else, you need to chown those too

Answer (score 7):

1. run `compaudit` and it will give you a list of directories it thinks are insecure
2. `sudo chown -R username:root target_directory`
3. `sudo chmod -R 755 target_directory`

Answer (score 7):

This was the only thing that worked for me from https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/issues/433#issuecomment-600582607. Thanks https://github.com/malaquiasdev!

```
  $ cd /usr/local/share/
  $ sudo chmod -R 755 zsh
  $ sudo chown -R root:staff zsh
```

Answer (score 6):

On macOS Sierra you need to run:
`sudo chown -R $(whoami):staff /usr/local`

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion would be to run compaudit and then just fix permissions on the directories found by the audit.
Make sure the identified directories do not have write permissions for group or other.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any answer that references the `homebrew` information on this topic: https://docs.brew.sh/Shell-Completion#configuring-completions-in-zsh

> To make Homebrew’s completions available in zsh, you must get the Homebrew-managed zsh site-functions on your FPATH before initialising zsh’s completion facility. Add the following to your ~/.zshrc file:

```
if type brew &>/dev/null; then
  FPATH=$(brew --prefix)/share/zsh/site-functions:$FPATH

  autoload -Uz compinit
  compinit
fi
```

> This must be done before compinit is called.

This solved the problem for me `without` manually changing ownership or otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

This morning, some packages in my system updated, and left me with this error message. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Apparently, something in the update changed the username and group to numbers, instead of `root`, as so:

```sh
# There are insecure files: /usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions/_code
# sudo ls -alh
-rw-r--r-- 1  131  142 2.6K 2019-10-10 16:28 _code
```

I simply changed the user and group for this file back to `root` and the problem went away. I did *not* need to change any permissions, and would caution against doing so unless the underlying cause of the problem is understood.

`sudo chown root _code && sudo chgrp root _code`

After switching `131` and `142` back to `root`, this error message from zsh went away.

Answer (score 3):

I got this issue after running the `google-cloud-sdk` install script, which adds command-completion to the shell via an entry in `.zshrc`.

Following [Homebrew's instructions for configuring completions in zsh](https://docs.brew.sh/Shell-Completion#configuring-completions-in-zsh) was helpful.

> Additionally, if you receive “zsh compinit: insecure directories” warnings when attempting to load these completions, you may need to run this: `chmod -R go-w "$(brew --prefix)/share"`

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions listed worked for me. Instead, I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling Homebrew, which did the trick. Uninstall instructions may be found here: http://osxdaily.com/2018/08/12/how-uninstall-homebrew-mac/

Answer (score 2):

Send a `y` character to the input stream of the script using `compinit`, in order to automatically answer the *Ignore insecure directories and files and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?* question

`echo "y" > source <GOOGLECLOUDSDK>/completion.zsh.inc`

The solution is useful when

- you **can't make ownership/access changes** to the folders
- when you **can't use the -u option** to remove the warning (probably because you don't explicitly call 'compinit' yourself, but it's called by a script you call)

**Remark:** It doesn't fix the problem and only hides the warning (as opposed to others answers here which involve removing 'group write access' or 'change ownership to root').