# Git tab completion in zsh throwing errors

Tags: git, zsh

After struggling to get tab completion for git setup on osx, I've gotten some odd errors that I can't find the source too.

```
zsh:12: command not found: ___main
_default:compcall:12: can only be called from completion function
```

I'm not sure what is causing the error as everything is setup correctly.

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' script ~/.git-completion.bash
autoload -U compinit && compinit
zmodload -i zsh/complist
source ~/.git-completion.zsh
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The solution mentioned in this post worked for me
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324516/483559

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It seems that the `git-completion.zsh` is **not** designed to be `source`ed. You could copy the `git-completion.zsh` file to somewhere in the `$fpath` and rename it to `_git` instead.

For example: (if you decide to have `~/.zsh/functions/_git`.)

First, you could copy the `git-completion.zsh` to there and rename it to `_git`.

`% mkdir -p ~/.zsh/functions && cp git-completion.zsh ~/.zsh/functions/_git`

Then you could have your `~/.zshrc` like this:

```sh
zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' script ~/.git-completion.bash
# `compinit` scans $fpath, so do this before calling it.
fpath=(~/.zsh/functions $fpath)
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

---

If I'm not sure, I do `rm ~/.zcompdump` to make sure that `compinit` discards its cache.

Comment: You are my hero :) Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You don't need the zstyle part; by default it will use `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git`.

Comment: You literally just completed my 1hr search. Thanks! - The `zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' script ~/.git-completion.bash` is no longer needed

Comment: This results in `__git_zsh_bash_func:8: command not found: __git_aliased_command` for me

Comment: got the same issue `__git_zsh_bash_func:8: command not found: __git_aliased_command` but the issue disappeared after restarting the terminal. also make sure the `gitfast` plugin disabled.

Comment: Im a little confused by the extensions. You mentioned git-completion.zsh and then in the .zshrc you have a dot bash file.

Comment: @HernanPintos Both two files are necessary to use the completion scripts in the Git distribution: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/tree/contrib/completion?h=v2.30.2 (We can see it by looking at `git-completion.zsh`, btw)

Comment: One thing I had to add: `compaudit | xargs chmod g-w` to avoid the warning `zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.` https://stackoverflow.com/a/66432105/2893090

Answer (score 7):

pre

```
mkdir -p ~/.zsh
cd ~/.zsh
```

get completion scripts

```
curl -o git-completion.bash https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
curl -o _git https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh
```

add to `~/.zshrc`

```
# git completion
zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' script ~/.zsh/git-completion.bash
fpath=(~/.zsh $fpath)
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

restart shell session