# zsh compinit: insecure directories. Compaudit shows /tmp directory

Tags: linux, zsh, zsh-completion

I'm running zsh on a Raspberry Pi 2 (Raspbian Jessie). zsh `compinit` is complaining about the `/tmp` directory being insecure. So, I checked the permissions on the directory:

```
$ compaudit
There are insecure directories:
/tmp
$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 13 root root 16384 Apr 10 11:17 /tmp
```

Apparently anyone can do anything in the /tmp directory. Which makes sense, given it's purpose. So I tried the suggestions on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762280/zsh-compinit-insecure-directories). I also tried similar suggestions on other sites. Specifiacally, it suggests turning off group write permissions on that directory. Because of how the permissions looked according to `ls -ld`, I had to turn off the 'all' write permissions as well. So:

```
$ sudo su
% chmod g-w /tmp
% chmod a-w /tmp
% exit
$ compaudit
# nothing shows up, zsh is happy
```

This shut zsh up. However, *other programs started to break*. For example, gnome-terminal would crash whenever I typed the letter 'l'. Because of this, I had to turn the write permissions back on, and just run `compinit -u` in my `.zshrc`.

What I want to know: ***is there any better way to fix this?*** I'm not sure that it's a great idea to let compinit use an insecure directory. My dotfiles repo is hosted [here](https://github.com/jo12bar/dotfiles), and the file where I now run `compinit -u` is [here](https://github.com/jo12bar/dotfiles/blob/master/zsh/zshrc.symlink).

Comment: Why is /tmp even in your `$fpath`? Does it actually contain completion files?

Comment: This has fixed for me Use This [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41674919/2511142)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the original permissions on `/tmp` were correct. Make sure you've restored them correctly: `ls -ld /tmp` must start with `drwxrwxrwt`. You can use `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp` to set the correct permissions. `/tmp` is supposed to be writable by everyone, and any other permissions is highly likely to break stuff.

`compaudit` complains about directories in `fpath`, so one of the directories in your `fpath` is of the form `/tmp/…` (not necessarily `/tmp` itself). Check how `fpath` is being set. Normally the directories in `fpath` should be only subdirectories of the zsh installation directory, and places in your home directory. A subdirectory of `/tmp` wouldn't get in there without something unusual on your part.

If you can't find out where the stray directory is added to `fpath`, run `zsh -x 2>zsh-x.log`, and look for `fpath` in the trace file `zsh-x.log`.

It *can* be safe to use a directory under `/tmp`, but only if you created it securely. The permissions on `/tmp` allow anybody to create files, but users can only remove or rename their own files (that's what [the `t` at the end of the permissions means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit#Usage)). So if a directory is created safely (e.g. with `mktemp -d`), it's safe to use it in `fpath`. `compaudit` isn't sophisticated enough to recognize this case, and in any case it wouldn't have enough information since whether the directory is safe depends on how it was created.

Comment: Thanks! `zsh -x 2>zsh-x.log` told me that I was loading the wrong files for my fpath. Apparently I was looping over oh-my-zsh's `$ZSH` variable instead of my `$DOTFILES_ZSH` variable (like I do everywhere else). Never would have caught it.