# Mac command line say "bad math expression: operand expected at end of string"

Tags: macos

On macbook terminal, when i hit the command TAB key after `ls`.
Terminal say error.

```
$ ls
_complete:96: bad math expression: operand expected at end of string
```

This example is `ls`, but other all command has same trouble.
I rebooted mac but trouble has not cleared.

What's happen do you know?

---

Mac was shutdown by himself automatically, and repaired before i knew it.

OS is:  OS X El Capitan.

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH`? Did you install any plugin?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this is.

umm i must remember libraries i installed today and check them.


    `$ echo $PATH`                                                                                                                                                        

    `/Users/yinaura/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin:/Users/yinaura/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/yinaura/.rbenv/shims:/Users/yinaura/.rbenv/bin:./vendor/bin:/Users/yinaura/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: Next time when adding info, [edit] your question ;)

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 32):

It's probably `oh-my-zsh` reporting insecure directory permissions.

Running `compaudit` in the terminal will show you those dirs. In my case it was:

```
/usr/local/share/zsh/
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

I my case removing group write permissions like this:

```
chmod g-w /usr/local/share/zsh/
chmod g-w /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

helped.

Or do just:

```
compaudit | xargs chmod g-w
```

as my shell suggests. (MacOS 11.2.1)

Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762280/zsh-compinit-insecure-directories).

Answer (score 18):

It might be because of zsh setup not done correctly. I also ran into the same issue this is how I fixed it.
I ran the below command and the issue got fixed. I am not sure what was the actual issue but yeah running this command worked for me.

> exec zsh

Comment: Worked for me too, no idea why the error was happening nor why it fixed.

Comment: This worked for me also. Thank you. Wish I knew the root cause however.

Answer (score 6):

For me doing `source .zshrc` was able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Some issue with zsh update causing this issue.

Just using `source ~/.zshrc` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case it can helps someone :

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

Answer (score -1):

I experience this problem after installing Homebrew on my new macOS Ventura (13) M1 Max (Mac Studio)

### **Step1**

```
compaudit
```

*Output:*
There are insecure directories:
/opt/homebrew/share

### **Step 2**

Either execute:

```
compaudit | xargs chmod g-w
```

The command will still give you "There are insecure directories:", but with an empty list (no directories will be listed)

OR

```
chmod g-w /opt/homebrew/share
```