# Connection to local postgresql database fails after upgrade to Big Sur

Tags: postgresql, macos-big-sur, datagrip

I use IntelliJ IDEA's bundled database client (DataGrip) to manage my database connections, both local and remote. And using docker to connect to postgres with following settings:

```
    services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:11
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=$user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=k$db
```

After upgrading from Catalina to Big Sur, connection to local db fails and it just shows a connection error message as follows:

```
    [08001] Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused).
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1252, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 966, in send
  File "site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
  File "site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 403, in increment
  File "site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1252, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 966, in send
  File "site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(61, 'Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 205, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 228, in _get
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(61, 'Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 123, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 69, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 132, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 188, in __init__
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 213, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(61, 'Connection refused'))
[1269] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Connecting to remote db's are not broken somehow, they work. Is there anyone came across this problem?

Comment: Please, post the error and environment specs (DB type, version and so on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Big Sur upgrade, I also had a warning whenever I open a new terminal:

```
    zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?
```

I did not think they are related but the solution to this problem, explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762280/zsh-compinit-insecure-directories/63447799#), also solved the main postgresql connection issue for me. But my computer keeps restarting occasionally and after this restart, I again get the main problem when I run `docker-compose up` inside IDE's terminal. I then manually restart and it works. Although not being a permanent soluiton, this solved my problem for now.