# nvm on MacOS init says: zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list

Tags: macos, shell, nvm

I have just installed and configures `nvm` (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
on macOS

as (in `.zshrc`)

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
export PATH=$PATH:$NVM_DIR
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

But every new Shell window or tab now warns about insecure directories

```
zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]? 
compinit: initialization aborted
complete:13: command not found: compdef
```

What to do with that?

---

More info

MacOS Catalina

using default zshell

nvm -v
0.38.0

[image]

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48153371/2125671

Comment: I don't want to play with system directories like /usr/local/share

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was adding this line to my `.zshrc` file

```
export ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX=true
```