# zsh compinit: insecure files, run compaudit for list. (_brew_services)

Tags: terminal, zsh

I am experiencing this error whenever the terminal starts up:

```
zsh compinit: insecure files, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure files and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?
```

I have tried the solutions from https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/issues/433

There is still one more insecure file that I are not able to solve:

```
There are insecure files:
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew_services
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, though with a different subdirectory. `_brew_services` is probably a symlink, you need to apply [the same fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13785716) to the directory it points to:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 $(readlink -f /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew_services)
sudo chown root:staff $(readlink -f /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew_services)
```

This fixed it for me.